# Errors when trying to run flutter app on M1 Max MacBook Pro

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, apple-m1

Okay. I am new to Flutter. I have a working Flutter app that runs just fine on my old MacBook Air. I now have a new computer... a bright, shiny, nice-smelling M1 Max MacBook Pro. The app won't run. I've tried a new flutter app. It won't run either. It runs on Chrome, and occasionally (40%) on iOS emulator, but then won't run on Android. I have absolutely no idea how to fix this because I don't understand what the problem(s) are. Supposedly VSCode, Android Studio, flutter all support Apple Silicon at this point. I've read a bunch of posts of people complaining about similar issues but the solutions either didn't work or they were for older releases that weren't yet supposedly supporting M1.
What I have done to attempt to fix the iOS emulator issue:

- uncommented the iOS version in Podfile, changed to 10.0
- ran sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi successfully

Didn't help.

Then, there is the Android emulator error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install /Users/home/Desktop/flutter_dev/rr_v1a/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk: 
Exception occurred while executing 'install':
android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
    at android.util.ExceptionUtils.wrap(ExceptionUtils.java:34)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.createSession(PackageInstallerService.java:557)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doCreateSession(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:3143)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.doRunInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1341)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runInstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1303)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:193)
    at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:24742)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:950)
    at and
Error launching application on sdk gphone64 arm64.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: The Android emulator isn't supported for the M1 on Android Studio.  You need to use a real device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the message you posted, emulator does not have enough space to install the app:

```
Requested internal only, but not enough space
```

You should check the settings for the emulator and check if you gave enough space. Also, I would recommend to install Android Studio (intel version) and run it with Rosseta. With this version you should be able to run android emulator but Apple Chip version will give some problems.

Comment: Thanks! I deleted the emulator and created another one and for now that seems to work. Can you explain to me why M1 would work on Intel version but not on Apple Chip version... it seem like it should be the other way around?

Comment: Android Studio Apple chip version has several bugs (for example in my case it doesn't open AVD manager, and it has issues with pods), but intel chip version works fine with no issues, it could be my setup but I saved some time using Intel chip version

Comment: Good to know! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: installing an intel version really helped and solved a lot of my problems that I was facing with silicon chip version and decide to keep quiet. A BIG THANK YOU!